# Referenced properties of generated custom entites class doesn't work

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have generated class with `CRM Devtoolkit`.
Got any entity throught `OrganizationServiceContext.CreateQuer<customEntityType>().Where(someExpression).FirstOfDefault()`. The result is fine. Is has all own properties but related Entities:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// N:N inv_inv_templatedelivery_account
    /// </summary>
    [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.RelationshipSchemaNameAttribute("relashionshipname")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CustomEntity> inv_inv_templatedelivery_account
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetRelatedEntities<CustomEntity>("relashionshipname", null);
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("somePointer");
            this.SetRelatedEntities<CustomEntity>("relashionshipname", null, value);
            this.OnPropertyChanged("somePointer");
        }
    }
```

This code was generated by SDK Developer Toolkit!
Why it returns NULL????
I also tried to generate  classes with CrmSvcUtil.exe - the same result.

Great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually force the loading of these related properties with the contact.LoadProeprty method:

`context.LoadProperty(entity, "inv_inv_templatedelivery_account");`

You wouldn't want CRM to pull back all of the data for all of the related items each time, so you have to specify each time what it is you want it to load.

Comment: Thanks, it was usefull!
But LoadProperty only allow to return data from this.GetRelatedEntities<CustomEntity>("relashionshipname", null).
It isn't to do with Lasy Loading